# Flowtype return value depending on input

Tags: flowtype

I *think* my question is easy, but nonetheless I could not find an answer anywhere.

I want to typecheck a function, but what I cannot seem to do is bind the return type to the input type.

Say I have a deck of cards that is typed, and I want a (imaginairy) return type that depends on the input given an existing mapping.

The deck with the function:

```
type Suit = "diamonds" | "clubs" | "hearts" | "spades"

const suitMapping = {
  "diamonds": ["are", "forever"],
  "clubs": ["fabric", "fuse"],
  "hearts": ["she", "loves", "me"],
  "spades": ["lemmy", "loud"]
}

const suitToList = (suit: Suit) => {
  return suitMapping[suit]
}
```

So for instance, I *know* that `suitToList("diamonds")` will return `["are", "forever"]`. And the mapping in the object is fixed and computer generated. But I would love it if there would be a way to typespec the mapping with Flow. That way, if somewhere down the road someone wants to add "motorhead" to "spades", the typecheck would fail at first, so the functions depending on the output could be checked.

For now, I have tests for it, but somewhere I feel this could be possible with Flow too.

Comment: Just to be clear... you want to find a way to distinguish `["are", "forever"]` from `["fabric", "fuse"]` on the type level? I'm not quite following how this would work - could you perhaps add a piece of example code which illustrates the situation where you'd want to see an error?

Answer (score 0):

I find a way to typecheck this, but with usage of `any`. Not too clean way, but I think it's a flow bug. See https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2057#issuecomment-395412981

```
type Suit = "diamonds" | "clubs" | "hearts" | "spades"

type SuitMapping = {
  diamonds: string,
  clubs: number,
  hearts: Array<string>,
  spades: Array<string>,
}

const suitMapping: SuitMapping = {
  "diamonds": '',
  "clubs": 1,
  "hearts": ["she", "loves", "me"],
  "spades": ["lemmy", "loud"]
}

const suitToList = <K: Suit>(suit: K): $ElementType<SuitMapping, K> => {        
  return (suitMapping[suit]: any);
}

// suitToList('xxx'); // error
// const x: number = suitToList('diamonds'); // error
const y: string = suitToList('diamonds'); // works
```

See on [flow try](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAygrgS2FAvFARAEwQQwLYD2AdpgM7pQA+GAxgDZwBG5VGAFhDgE7AvXqkwOTBHIAoMaEixEwALI4wYBEQDmqKAG8xUKNnzEyALiilgXFaoA0OqPSakTROHkYQuN3R268TAQS4uHBAAHjMLNQA+T1MhEUcoAKDQ8MtosQBfCRpiM1NZBSVLE3gkQuU1DW1dLFxCEnITAHImmPR7ZnQTAEY27x5GqABtAQ50Kww6AgA3UXGMPAh0AF02wWE5kxG6CDw8EHn0KbhMFczs3ORSWQAVAgAZBDy0EIBpEtlIgAprpBNXgCUJgAJABRHaLIjAG7gCAhUryRQVaxQV6RVDozS6bHY2xcCDAOBcIhQH4FJGWIa-YDLEw4IggAEAbnOOJxYgA9Bz8kg7o8zF8mgAPEVNZlQLlQdxcAhcTncnJEPJCpwuNxcDTUvlPYCC-T1MhipkS7nS2ViRV5EAmVKVNBah46vV1QykI0mqAAd1lAGtSEA)